# Live preview inside iFrame and saving style.css every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, iframe

I am making a website where you type in CSS and there is a preview (preview.php) - which is shown inside an iFrame - which has set text. I would like preview.php to update live to when you type CSS into the css file (relative to preview.php: `designname/css/style.css`), and to save the edited CSS file every 30 seconds.

#### EDIT

How should I edit the text in the `style` tag instead of a file, and uploading the text that you type into an actual file (`title_of_design/css/style.css`), and uploading any images (when you enter in that you need them in an Image Field) to the directory `title_of_design/image.php?i=image+name` or `title_of_design/images/image_name.png`?

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: @Aristona I have made the page to edit on (just the style) and preview.php (just the preview text that will be shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="style" placeholder="Enter CSS here!"></textarea>
<iframe id="preview" src="preview.php"></iframe>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// Automatic update
$("#style").keyup(function() {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $("#preview").attr("src", "preview.php?code=" + encodeURIComponent(txt));
});

// Auto-save
setInterval(function() {
    $.post("save.php", {"code": $("#style").val() }, function() {
        alert("Successfully saved!");
    });
}, 30 * 1000);
```

*This example assumes you are using jQuery*

**PHP:**

In your `preview.php` file, inside the `<head>` tag, place the following code:

```
<style><?php echo htmlentities($_GET['code']); ?></style>
```

In your `save.php` file, place the following code:

```
<?php
$code = $_POST['code'];

file_put_contents("title_of_design/css/style.css", $code);
?>
```

**Images:**

Images are more complicated, but I recommend you take a look at the [W3Schools PHP file upload tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

Comment: How would I make the user also be able to change the HTML on the page (save it too) with a TextArea with an ID of `html`?

Comment: Use the same code as style, but for html. Also, change the URL on line 4 of the Javascript code to `"preview.php?css=" + encodeURIComponent(txt) + "&html=" + encodeURIComponent($("#html").val())`. It's really very easy.